# How to flip geom_boxplot and rescale axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a boxplot that I am flipping using `coord_flip()`. I am also trying to rescale the boxplot x-axis using `coord_cartesian()` but when I do, the boxplot is no longer flipped. I keep getting the phrase `Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.` everytime I attempt to make the boxplot. How can I flip my boxplot and rescale the x-axis?

Note: I have also tried using `coord_fixed()` in place of `coord_cartesian()` to rescale but that also did not work.

Example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Load the mtcars dataset
data(mtcars)

data <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg,cyl)

# Add outliers to specific groups
outliers <- data.frame(
  mpg = c(45,50,55,45,50,55),
  cyl = c(4,4,4,8,8,8))

# Create example dataset
data <- rbind(data, outliers)

# Flip axis and show outliers
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

```r
 
# Attempt to flip axis and rescale x-axis to not show outliers
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  coord_flip() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 45))
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will
#> replace the existing one.
```

[image]

```r
# Attemp to flip axis and rescale x-axis to not show outliers
# Perhaps xlim should ylim?
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  coord_flip() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 45))
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will
#> replace the existing one.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Use `coord_flip(ylim=c(0, 45))` and remove `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 45))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792244/dave2e) said, use `ylim` (and/or `xlim`) to change the limits of the graph area:

```
library(tidyverse)

outliers <- data.frame(
  mpg = c(45,50,55,45,50,55),
  cyl = c(4,4,4,8,8,8))

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg,cyl) %>%
    bind_rows(outliers)  %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    coord_flip(xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0,50))

# Below is what I liked, but you can move things however you want by changing the values of xlim and ylim. Go nuts!
```

[image: boxplot with strange borders]

Credit: [Dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792244/dave2e)